# "java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module" this error happens after firebase updated there artifacts

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-play-services

```
e: C:/Users/USER-DIRECTORY/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d0733e98db50bf72d2f0482087ca7918/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.     

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 37s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          278.1s
```

So, this is the error Im facing right now in my Flutter Project. After Google and Firebase updated their artifacts on last October 30, 2023. [Google here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) and [Firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2023-10-30).

this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}
```

for my app/build.gradle

```
android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.parkbai.com"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I dont know what's the problem here and I've searched through other sites to help me but none of those helped my case.

I want to build an apk for my Android Flutter App and can run afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'` in `android/build.gradle`.

More details can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/17pzika/module_was_compiled_with_an_incompatible_version/)